# How are the factors obtained at *this point* in the solution of proving $2^{2^n}+ 1 \mid 2^{2^m} -1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

**I understood everything up until "BUT".  My question is how are the factors on the right side for the bolded line of equation under the word "BUT" obtained?  I tried to get these factors using property (5), but I was unsuccessful, can someone please show me how to get those factors?  Thanks in advance.**

This is example 2 from "Problems of Number Theory in Mathematical Competitions" by You Hong-Bing on page 2.

Some properties the example will be using are:

(1) If $b\mid c$, and $c\mid a$, then $b\mid a$, that is, divisibility is transitive.

(5) If $n$ is a positive odd number, then

$x^n-y^n= (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \ldots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$

*The problem, example 2 is as follows:*

**Let $\mathbf{m > n}$ and $\mathbf{n\ge 0}$, show that $\mathbf{(2^{2^n}+1)\mid(2^{2^m}-1)}$**

*The following is the proof from the book:*

Take $x=2^{2^{n+1}}$,$\,\,y=1$ in factorization (5), and substitute $n$ by $2^{m-n-1}$

WE GET:

$2^{2^m}-1 = (2^{2^{n+1}}-1) \left[(2^{2^{n+1}})^{2^{m-n-1}-1} +\ldots +  2^{2^{n+1}}+1 \right]$

THUS,

$(2^{2^{n+1}}-1) \mid (2^{2^m}-1)$

BUT,

$\mathbf{(2^{2^{n+1}}-1) = (2^{2^n} - 1)(2^{2^n} + 1)}$
This is the equation I'm having trouble with so everything else after this didn't make much sense to me

HENCE,

$(2^{2^n} + 1)\mid(2^{2^{n+1}} - 1)$

FURTHER, BY PROPERTY (1) WE HAVE:

$(2^{2^n} +1)\mid(2^{2^m} - 1)$

REMARK: sometimes it is difficult to prove $b\mid a$ directly when dealing with divisibility problems.  Therefore, we can attempt to choose an "intermediate number" $c$ and prove $b\mid c$ and $c\mid a$ first, then use property (1) of divisibility to deduce the conclusion.

Comment: Hint: $(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2^{2^{n+1}}=2^{(2^{n+1})}=\left(2^{2^n}\right)^2$
So   $2^{2^{n+1}}-1=\left(2^{2^n}\right)^2-1$
and you can factor it as the difference of squares into

$\left(2^{2^n}-1\right)\left(2^{2^n}+1\right)$

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
$x^{2^m}-1
=(x-1)\prod_{n=0}^{m-1}(x^{2^n}+1)
$.
For this,
put $x = 2$.

Proof.

For $m=1$ this is
$x^{2^1}-1
=(x-1)\prod_{n=0}^{0}(x^{2^n}+1)
$
or
$x^2-1
=(x-1)(x+1)
$.

If it is true for $m$ then

$\begin{array}\\
(x-1)\prod_{n=0}^{(m+1)-1}(x^{2^n}+1)
&=(x-1)\prod_{n=0}^{m}(x^{2^n}+1)\\
&=(x-1)(x^{2^m}+1)\prod_{n=0}^{m-1}(x^{2^n}+1)\\
&=(x^{2^m}+1)(x-1)\prod_{n=0}^{m-1}(x^{2^n}+1)\\
&=(x^{2^m}+1)(x^{2^m}-1)
\qquad\text{(induction hypothesis)}\\
&=x^{2^{m+1}}-1
\qquad (x^a+1)(x^a-1)=x^{2a}-1
\text{ and } 2(2^m) = 2^{m+1}\\
\end{array}
$